# Xamarin.Auth - UWP - Redirection URL interecepted by Windows

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.auth

I am using the package **Xamarin.Auth** to authenticate an user against an authentication service within my UWP App.

The authenticator is instantiated like the following:

```
this.Authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    "openid profile",
    new Uri("https://<authentication-example-server>/authorize"),
    new Uri("my-app://oauth2redirect"),
    new Uri("https://<authentication-example-server>/access_token"),
    GetUsernameAsync,
    isUsingNativeUI: false);
this.Authenticator.Completed += this.OnAuthenticationCompleted;
```

Later I launch the authentication process:

```
var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
presenter.Login(this.Authenticator);
```

Everything works as expected so far and authentication works fine. However, I get an issue on the redirection. Although the redirection with the custom URL calls the app itself and calls the method

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
```

as expected,
Windows always triggers an additional dialogue window:
[image: Did you meant to switch apps?]

How can I avoid that interception of the authentication process without changing a registry or any system wide settings? Actually, the app is only calling itself and therefore I cannot understand, why the mesage is triggered. Do I have to use another redirection approach?

I also tried to user isUsingNativeUI: true and nothing changed.

Comment: I know this is several months late, but did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry, actually, I did not solve this problem directly. I removed the OAuth2Authenticator and implemented a little OAuth solution myself (for my simple usecase). Basically I call my authentication provider site in a `WebView`, register for the `WebViewNavigating`-Event and handle the event when the `WebView` "returns" with the token.
Unfortunately I cannot provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the redirection parameter(`my-app://oauth2redirect`) was regarded app launch uri. You could modify the it to another, such as `https://auth0.com/`

```
this.Authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    "openid profile",
    new Uri("https://<authentication-example-server>/authorize"),
    new Uri("https://auth0.com/"),
    new Uri("https://<authentication-example-server>/access_token"),
    GetUsernameAsync,
    isUsingNativeUI: false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately using this approach OnActivated does not get called and therefore Xamarin.Auth does not go on handling the authentication process.

Comment: You could check this [document](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/GettingStarted#11-create-and-configure-an-authenticator) and use correct `redirectUrl` for current scenario.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT your solution does not allow OnActivated to get called and the link provided in your comment does not have complete implementation scenarios for windows apps